# RxJS: How may I treat bindNodeCallback() as an Observable that can have operators chained to it?

Tags: node.js, rxjs, rxjs6

For RxJS learning purposes, I'm building a small node.js app that puts everything in a stream where possible.

As a first step, I'm working to load an external configuration yaml file. I've seen examples where fs.readFile is wrapped in a bindNodeCallback, which returns an observable when called. However, the readFile variable set below is still a `typeof` of 'function'. As a result, I'm unable to chain flatMap to it.

How may I reorganize the code below to chain bindNodeCallback() and yaml.safeLoad() (which doesn't offer a callback) before initializing my app?

```
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const fs = require('fs');
const { bindNodeCallback, of } = require('rxjs');
const { mergeMap, map } = require('rxjs/operators');

const configPath = './config/config.yml';
const configEncoding = 'utf8';

const readFile = bindNodeCallback(fs.readFile);

readFile(configPath, configEncoding)
.flatMap(yamlString => of(yaml.safeLoad(yamlString))) // error: .flatMap is not a funciton
.subscribe(
    config => {
        console.log(config);
        // launch the app when config is loaded
    }, 
    err => console.error(err)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readFile` should still be a function, and it does return an `Observable` when executed, but `flatMap` is not a method on the `Observable` that's returned. If you get rid of the call to `.flatMap()` and jump straight to `.subscribe()`, that works.

Were you trying to use `flatMap` from `rxjs/operators`, or the chaining interface?

---

This works, but I had to `yarn add rxjs-compat` for some reason. Also note that I swapped to using `Observable#pipe()` with `flatMap` as a pipeable operator.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const yaml = require('js-yaml')
const { bindNodeCallback } = require('rxjs')
const { flatMap } = require('rxjs/operators')
const { of } = require('rxjs/observable/of')

const configPath = './config.yml'
const configEncoding = 'utf8'

const readFile = bindNodeCallback(fs.readFile)

readFile(configPath, configEncoding)
  .pipe(flatMap(yamlString => of(yaml.safeLoad(yamlString))))
  .subscribe(
    config => {
      console.log(config)
    },
    err => console.error(err),
  )
```

Comment: Absorbing momentarily. Thank you for your answer. 

Main goal was to load data, convert to obj, maybe even validate, then pass on to the next thing when all done. I wasn't aware of the difference between operator and chaining interface for this yet.

Comment: Sure - I think you can still add operators to the `Observable` prototype if you want to, but I think pipeable operators tend to be more preferred now. This might help you: https://www.learnrxjs.io/concepts/operator-imports.html